# Google places api issues

Tags: android, ios, google-places-api

About 6 months ago I developed mobile apps for both IOS and Android, I created an app like uber for that I used google places API and it was working fine but I recently come to know that the google places API just stopped working on both apps but it is still working on my web application. 
I also checked my billing but it is fine and having no issues at all. 
Request quota is also not an issue.
SDK is also updated (Updated SDK about 6 months ago).
I appreciate your response.
Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Hi, what version of the SDK are you running? You can see it in the Podfile.lock if you are using Pods.

Comment: I am using 16.0.0

Comment: Not sure about 16.0.0, I see that the latest one is 3.6.0 (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/releases). Version 2.7.0 was deprecated and turned off on July 29, 2019, so if you were running this version, that could be a reason.

Comment: @Sam but the issue is our app just started to crash about two days ago before that it was working fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "places API just stopped working"? Also, if you run the project in Xcode do you get any relevant info/errors?

Comment: before yesterday when I enter something in search box it shows places suggestion from google but now when I try to type something in the search box it did not show any suggestions from google place APIs

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the search screen and some code so we can try to identify? It's hard to try and find a solution without seeing anything since there can be so many reasons for such behavior.

Comment: thank you @all for help i found out it has something to do with updated google places api

Comment: Glad to be helpful! Thank you for letting us know.